# How to manage API function call services in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, angular2-services

I finished an Angular 7 web app (Roughly). As an example, I have a documents.service.ts file and it includes below HTTP GET request function:

```
public sendOnlyCoverPage(strProNo: string, strEstesFileName: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(this.FilesApi + "/GetSendOnlyCoverPage?strProNo=" + strProNo + '&strEstesFileName=' + strEstesFileName, httpOptions);
}
```

And POST request is like below format:

```
public FTP_PutFile(ftpModel: any): Observable<any> {
    var obj = JSON.stringify(ftpModel);
    return this._http.post(this.FilesApi + "/PostFTP_PutFile", obj, httpOptions);
}
```

I have two questions:

**Question 1:**

I have a lot HTTP GET and POST functions in different services such as above. I feel like I am doing something wrong about API function design because when I open any serivce file, there are a lot functions like above. I am thinking that is there any way to centralize these api functions. Such as I can create a middle service and whenever I need to make an API call, I can pass function name, url and parameter etc.

**Question 2:**

As the code shows above, I have parameter **ftpModel: any**. I understand it is better to create a object mapping (interface) to replace the any type. BUT again, there are a lot parameters like this one. Is there any solution for that instead of creating each object mapping (interface) for each parameter?

Comment: The whole point of such servces is precisely to give a readable, easy to call,  type-safe, easy to mock higher abstraction over the raw HttpClient. If you offer very generic methods that all take any as arguments, then a service isn't useful anymore: HttpClient already offers that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**
You should create a abstract BaseService, something like this:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

export abstract class BaseService<T> {
  private endpoint: string;

  constructor(protected http: HttpClient,
              endpoint: string) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
  }

  findAll(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.http.get<T[]>(this.getUrl());
  }

  findOne(id: number): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(`${this.getUrl()}/${id}`);
  }

  save(objeto: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.post<T>(this.getUrl(), objeto);
  }

  delete(id: number): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.delete<void>(`${this.getUrl()}/${id}`);
  }

  protected getUrl(): string {
    return `${environment.api_url}${this.endpoint}`;
  }

  complete(query: string): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.http.get<T[]>(`${this.getUrl()}/complete?query=${query}`);
  }

}
```

And also, extends it in your services:

```
export class ProductService extends BaseService<Product> {

  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {
    super(http, 'product');
  }
}
```

A example in [My github](https://github.com/lucini/pedidos-bootcamp/blob/master/src/app/service/base.service.ts)

**Question 2**
The better approach still is what you mentioned, create your classes/interfaces for mapping.